# Two divs with inline-flex and different flex-direction changes the y position of element

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've come into a strange situation where two divs with `display: inline-block` with different flex-directions are not lining up vertically. Anyone know how to fix this?

`flex-direction: row-reverse`
[image: flex-direction:row-reverse]

`flex-direction:row`
[image: flex-direction:row]

```css
.swiper-navigation {
  display: inline-flex;
  background-color: #001440;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #001440;
  padding: 0 15px;
  font-size: 24px;
  height: 70px;
  font-family: serif;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 2;
  gap: 10px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.swiper-navigation__fraction {
  // transform: translateY(-3px);
}

.swiper-navigation__fraction strong {
  color: #c8103e;
}

.swiper-navigation__arrow {
  fill: white;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}

.swiper-navigation--next {
  flex-direction: row;
}

.swiper-navigation--prev {
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.swiper-navigation--prev .swiper-navigation__arrow {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.swiper-navigation:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #001440;
}

.swiper-navigation:hover .swiper-navigation__arrow {
  fill: #001440;
}
```

```html
<div class="swiper-navigation swiper-navigation--prev" tabIndex={0} role="button">
  <div class="swiper-navigation__fraction">
    01<strong>/</strong>03
  </div>
  <svg class="swiper-navigation__arrow" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="Swiper_swiper-navigation__arrow__NgmVM"><path d="M12 4l-1.41 1.41L16.17 11H4v2h12.17l-5.58 5.59L12 20l8-8z"></path></svg>
</div>
<div class="swiper-navigation swiper-navigation--next" tabIndex={0} role="button">
  <div class="swiper-navigation__fraction">
    03<strong>/</strong>03
  </div>
  <svg class="swiper-navigation__arrow" viewBox="0 0 24 24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="Swiper_swiper-navigation__arrow__NgmVM"><path d="M12 4l-1.41 1.41L16.17 11H4v2h12.17l-5.58 5.59L12 20l8-8z"></path></svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `vertical-align: top;` to the div seems to fix the issue.